# getopt: параметр со значением по умолчанию

Tags: python, python-2.x, argparse, getopt

Возможно ли объяснить `getopt`, что на входе может быть параметр, который может содержать, а может и не содержать аргумента? Если я делаю так:

```
import getopt
import sys

optlist, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "b:")
for (x, y) in optlist:
    print x, y
```

и запускаю скрипт без аргумента у параметра `$ python t.py -b`, то получаю на выходе ошибку

`getopt.GetoptError: option -b requires argument`.

А если делаю так:

```
optlist, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "b")
```

и запускаю скрипт с параметром, содержащим аргумент `$ python t.py -b 11`, то он этот аргумент не распознаёт.

Или по другому, можно ли задать параметру значение по умолчанию?

Нужно, чтобы я мог в командной строке:

1. не указывать параметр - значит его нет;
2. указывать параметр без аргумента - значит параметр есть, а его значения равно None или оно берётся по умолчанию;
3. указывать параметр с аргументом - значит есть параметр и он имеет значение

Comment: @insolor, нет, не сработал такой вариант

Comment: А нет варианта не использовать getopt?) Взять или стандартный argparse, или какой-нибудь click, например.

Comment: @insolor, я попробовал реализовать данную идею с помощью argparse, но не вышло. Там, при добавлении аргумента есть параметр ```default```, но он говорит о том, что будет создан параметр с конкретным значением, даже если его не передать в командной строке. А мне нужно другое

Comment: А что другое нужно?

Comment: @insolor, нужно, чтобы я мог в командной строке: 1) не указывать параметр - значит его нет; 2) указывать параметр без аргумента - значит параметр есть, а его значения раво None или оно берётся по умолчанию; 3) указывать параметр с аргументом - значит есть параметр и он имеет значение

Comment: Если вариант с argparse все-таки подойдет, я чуть позже напишу ответ.

Comment: @insolor, подойдёт

Comment: Первый пункт не получается - все равно создается параметр со значением по умолчанию.

Comment: @insolor, да, а для меня это важно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покопался в исходниках `argparse`, итог такой: можно вызывать не метод `parse`, а внутренний метод [`_parse_known_args`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4d7f11e05731f67fd2c07ec2972c6cb9861d52be/Lib/argparse.py#L1863), передавая в него пустой `Namespace`, тогда при отсутствии ключа он не будет появляться внутри `Namespace` (правда, так не будет учитываться параметр `default` в `add_argument`):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-b', type=int, nargs='?')


def test(args):
    print(args, parser._parse_known_args(args, argparse.Namespace())[0])


test([])
test(['-b'])
test(['-b', '42'])
```

Вывод:

```
[] Namespace()
['-b'] Namespace(b=None)
['-b', '42'] Namespace(b=42)
```

Лучше, конечно, не использовать внутренние методы напрямую, но если очень хочется, то можно.

Comment: Благодарю! Очень помог Ваш ответ